# Common method for 2 interfaces

Tags: c#, interface

I have a little design question in C#.

I have an IAnimal interface (with some methods).
Then I have an IMammal and IReptile interfaces (inheriting both the IAnimal interface).

What should I do if a method appears to be necessary to both IMammal and IReptil classes?

I can't put this method in the IAnimal interface because it concerns only IMammal and IReptile (and no other animals) but I don't to define this method twice (doesn't sound good practice).

Comment: How about putting it in a new interface that only `IMammal` and `IReptile` implement?

Comment: `IVertebrate`? ... and so on?

Comment: Creating nested hierarchies can get messy. You might create one interface that includes mammals and reptiles, put something in that interface, and then another type that's neither a mammal nor a reptile needs it. Now you're painted into a corner. Instead, think in terms of interfaces for different behaviors and create classes that compose them into the combinations you want. That way you're getting reuse but you're not coupling things together that you might need to separate later.

Comment: Prefer method duplication to nonsensical inheritance.

Comment: Well, it depends on whether you have use cases where you want to treat mammals and reptiles as the same type of entity (with regard to the method/behavior/trait in question). If you don't have such a use case, no need to introduce another layer of interfaces, just keep the method definitions separately in both the mammal and reptile interfaces. If you have use cases where you want to treat mammals and reptiles as the same type of entity (with regard to the method), follow the advice in the 1st comment...

Comment: If you ever had need to change that method contract on IMammal(say add an extra parameter or change some int to a long), would you expect to change IReptile the same way or is this a question that to would need to consider on a case by case basis?

Answer (score 2):

Mostly what you are talking about is *Interface Segregation* and thus instead putting in a single interface, you can define a separate one which only  `IMammal` and `IReptil` would implement or inherit from.

As an alternative, you can as well `throw NotImplementedException()` for other types which don't concern the behavior.

Comment: I think you mean NotSupportedException. Leave NotImplementedException for its intended purpose. I don't personally like NotSupportedException. It is almost always a code smell that indicates poor Interface segregation. But fwiw the framework itself does it too

Comment: Seconding that. A finished class should never have a method that does nothing but throw an exception. NotSupportedException and NotImplementedException result in a class that both implements an interface and doesn't implement it. It solves a compile error by introducing a runtime error. The whole point is to do exactly the opposite of that. 
*I called a method and got an exception. Is it broken? No. That's the exception-throwing method. Don't call that method.*
Do we see why that's bad? It's the exact opposite of trying to write code that *doesn't* throw exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Both `IMammal` and `IReptile` implement `IMammalReptile` that implements itself `IAnimal`. You create an additional level in your interface hierarchy. This makes sense when you think of the relationship along the lines of `IMammal` *is a* `IMammalReptile`
2. You create a third interface that defines the desired behavior and make both `IMammal` and `IReptile` implement it along with `IAnimal`. This makes sense when you think of the relationship along the lines of `IMammal` *behaves like*.

In your particular case with the given examples, option 2 seems the way to go.

Comment: Anybody suggesting `IMammalReptile` failed their ecology/biology classes lol.

Comment: @sturcotte06 :) touché. Thats part of the reason why I suggest option 2.

Comment: Made me smile though hahaha

Answer (score 0):

You can create a common interface that both `IMammal` and `IReptile` implement. But in practice we're less likely to write code that handles all of those nested types. It can also paint you into a corner. Something will need the common method used by mammals and reptiles, but it won't be compatible with some lower-level interface.

Instead, try creating interfaces like `IMoveBehavior`, `IEatBehavior`, `IReproduceBehavior` and placing the various behaviors in their own classes.

That way if you want a given implementation of `IMoveBehavior` you can use it in any type of animal, even if it has nothing else in common with other animals that use that behavior.

You can still use inheritance. Perhaps you "compose" a frog from various behaviors, and now you need different types of frogs. They might have so much in common that inheritance makes sense. But it's better to start with composition and then see if a pattern emerges where inheritance benefits us. If we start with inheritance it tends to trip us up.